# Configure External Run in PyScripter to run IronPython

Tags: ironpython, pyscripter

Any Iron PyScripter's in da the house?  I'm seeking the "External Run" parameters/variables needed to configure IronPython to run the current script.  I don't understand any of variable examples, so verbatim instructions or a screen shot of how to configure the "External Tools Properties" configuration page is really what I need.  Thanx!